# Vizualize distance matrix into graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graphviz, distance-matrix

For the following distance matrix:

```
∞, 1, 2
∞, ∞, 1
∞, ∞, ∞
```

I would need to visualise the following graph:
[That's how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qkfu.png)

I tried with the following code:

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import string

dt = [('len', float)]
A = np.array([ (0, 1, None, 3, None),
               (2, 0, 4, 1, None),
               (5, None, 0, 3, None),
               (None, None, None, 0, None),
               (None, None, None, 2, 0),
               ])*10
A = A.view(dt)

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)   

G = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)

G.node_attr.update(color="red", style="filled")
G.edge_attr.update(color="blue", width="2.0")

G.draw('out.png', format='png', prog='neato')
```

but I cannot seem to input infinity (∞) to show that there is no connection. I tried with `None`, `-1`, and even `∞` but nothing seems to work right, so if anyone has any idea how I can visualise that distance matrix, please let me know.

Comment: Do you want to create the underlying unweighted directed graph? That means you would only create an edge for those entries in your distance matrix, if the value is exactly 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not immediately obvious if this is what you are after, but one option is to use `np.inf` to denote the infinity. Below is a snippet where edges with value `np.inf` are removed, but whether this makes sense will depend on the context:

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

A = np.array(
    [
        (0, 1, np.inf),
        (2, 0, 4),
        (5, np.inf, 0),
    ],
    dtype="float",
)

# if edge is np.inf replace with zero
A[A == np.inf] = 0

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
G = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)
G.node_attr.update(color="red", style="filled")
G.edge_attr.update(color="blue", width="0.3")
G.draw("out.png", format="png", prog="neato")
```